# Export Table in Query to email VBA

Tags: email, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to export one of my queries to email using VBA in a table format. Similar to when you go to external data and click and E-Mail and it adds an attachment to outlook. Except I want it in the body. I put the following code in a button.

I found and made some changes to some code. This is what I have.

```
Private Sub Command5_Click()
Dim olApp As Object
Dim olItem As Variant
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rec As DAO.Recordset
Dim strQry As String
Dim aHead(1 To 4) As String
Dim aRow(1 To 4) As String
Dim aBody() As String
Dim lCnt As Long

'Create the header row
aHead(1) = "Part"
aHead(2) = "Description"
aHead(3) = "Qty"
aHead(4) = "Price"

lCnt = 1
ReDim aBody(1 To lCnt)
aBody(lCnt) = "<HTML><body><table border='2'><tr><th>" & Join(aHead, "</th>    <th>") & "</th></tr>"

'Create each body row
strQry = "SELECT * From qry_email"
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strQry)

If Not (rec.BOF And rec.EOF) Then
Do While Not rec.EOF
    lCnt = lCnt + 1
    ReDim Preserve aBody(1 To lCnt)
    aRow(1) = rec("Part")
    aRow(2) = rec("Description")
    aRow(3) = rec("Qty")
    aRow(4) = rec("Price")
    aBody(lCnt) = "<tr><td>" & Join(aRow, "</td><td>") & "</td></tr>"
    rec.MoveNext
Loop
End If

aBody(lCnt) = aBody(lCnt) & "</table></body></html>"

'create the email
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
Set olItem = olApp.CreateItem(0)

olItem.Display
olItem.To = "email@email.com"
olItem.Subject = "Test E-mail"
olItem.HTMLBody = Join(aBody, vbNewLine)
olItem.Display

End Sub
```

When I run the code, I get a "Run-time error '3061' too few parameters. Expected 1."

If i click debug i get this highlighted in yellow. Anybody help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit

I tried a different approach which actually gave me the list in the body of the email. But it does it for the whole table instead of just the one record I want. This is what the SQL looks like of the query.

```
SELECT tblePMParts.[Part#], tblePMParts.PartDescription, tblePMParts.Qty,      tblePMParts.Price
FROM tblePMParts
WHERE (((tblePMParts.WOID)=[Forms]![fmremail]![Text1]));
```

How would I go about adding the WHERE to the code below.

```
Private Sub Command4_Click()


'On Error GoTo Errorhandler

Dim olApp As Object
Dim olItem As Variant
Dim olatt As String
Dim olMailTem As Variant
Dim strSendTo As String
Dim strMsg As String
Dim strTo As String
Dim strcc As String
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qry As DAO.QueryDef
Dim fld As Field
Dim varItem As Variant
Dim strtable As String
Dim rec As DAO.Recordset
Dim strQry As String




strQry = "SELECT tblePMParts.[Part#], tblePMParts.PartDescription,  tblePMParts.Qty, tblePMParts.Price  " & _
         "FROM tblePMParts; "

strSendTo = "test@email.com"

strTo = ""
strcc = ""

Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
Set olItem = olApp.CreateItem(olMailTem)

olItem.Display
olItem.To = strTo
olItem.CC = strcc
olItem.Body = ""
olItem.Subject = "Please Quote the Following!"

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strQry)
If Not (rec.BOF And rec.EOF) Then
    rec.MoveLast
    rec.MoveFirst
    intCount = rec.RecordCount
        For intLoop = 1 To intCount
            olItem.Body = olItem.Body & rec("[Part#]") & " - " &     rec("PartDescription") & " - " & rec("Qty") & " - " & rec("Price")
            rec.MoveNext
        Next intLoop
End If

MsgBox "Completed Export"
Set olApp = Nothing
Set olItem = Nothing

Exit_Command21_Click:
Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description, , Err.Number
Resume Exit_Command21_Click

End Sub
```

I got it working. Here is the code in case anybody needs it.

```
Private Sub Command5_Click()
Dim olApp As Object
Dim olItem As Variant
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rec As DAO.Recordset
Dim strQry As String
Dim aHead(1 To 3) As String
Dim aRow(1 To 3) As String
Dim aBody() As String
Dim lCnt As Long

'Create the header row
aHead(1) = "Part#"
aHead(2) = "Description"
aHead(3) = "Qty"

lCnt = 1
ReDim aBody(1 To lCnt)
aBody(lCnt) = "<HTML><body><table border='2'><tr><th>" & Join(aHead, "</th><th>") & "</th></tr>"

'Create each body row
strQry = "SELECT tblePMParts.[Part#], tblePMParts.PartDescription,  tblePMParts.Qty, tblePMParts.Price  " & _
 "FROM tblePMParts " & _
 "WHERE (((tblePMParts.WOID)=" & [Forms]![fmremail]![Text1] & "));"
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strQry)

If Not (rec.BOF And rec.EOF) Then
    Do While Not rec.EOF
        lCnt = lCnt + 1
        ReDim Preserve aBody(1 To lCnt)
        aRow(1) = rec("[Part#]")
        aRow(2) = rec("PartDescription")
        aRow(3) = rec("Qty")
        aBody(lCnt) = "<tr><td>" & Join(aRow, "</td><td>") & "</td></tr>"
        rec.MoveNext
    Loop
End If

aBody(lCnt) = aBody(lCnt) & "</table></body></html>"

'create the email
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
Set olItem = olApp.CreateItem(0)

olItem.Display
olItem.To = "Email"
olItem.Subject = "Test E-mail"
olItem.HTMLBody = Join(aBody, vbNewLine)
olItem.Display

End Sub
```

Comment: Does qry_email run?

Comment: @Fionnuala Sorry I am new to using VBA but how would I tell the qry_email is actually running. I edited the original post with a different approach instead. The method works but I don't know how to add the WHERE part to the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in your code, put a line that says

```
X = [Forms]![fmremail]![Text1]
```

Put a breakpoint in your code (hopefully you know how to do that?) on that line. When the code breaks, press F8 to step to the next line, and then type ?X in the Immediate Window. Or you can just hover your mouse over the line with the break point. The point is, you need to see what your code thinks [Forms]![fmremail]![Text1] is equal to. If it's null, you have a problem with your reference.  In that case, you may need to add ".Value" or ".Text" to the end of it.

Another thing to check is your datatype for WOID. if it's text, you need to surround it with single quotes.

```
strQry = "SELECT tblePMParts.[Part#], tblePMParts.PartDescription,  tblePMParts.Qty, tblePMParts.Price  " & _
     "FROM tblePMParts " & _
     "WHERE (((tblePMParts.WOID)='" & [Forms]![fmremail]![Text1] & "'));"
```

Comment: I changed it to specific record and it worked beautifully. For example this worked "WHERE tblePMParts.WOID= 907;" . Having the textbox doesn't I tried adding single quotes and it didn't work. The Text1 is a text box in a form.